# Calculate Age from date stored in database in Y-m-d using Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, database, date, laravel-5

Hi User's add their DOB through the Form that store in database,

I would like calculate age from stored date in the database which is in this format Y-m-d,

My Question is :

- How to calculate Age?
- Where to put the logic , In Controller or Model?
- How to pass the stored Date in view in this format 'm-d-Y'
- How to pass the result of logic which is age in view.
- I am using something as below in my model is this Right?

This is controller:

```
public function index()   {   
    $profile   = User::find($this->userid())->profiledetailsHasOne;  //This has Dob field                   
    return view('profile.index',['profile' => $profile ]); 
}
```

This is my Model:

```
public function getAge(){
    $this->birthdate->diff($this->attributes['dob'])
    ->format('%y years, %m months and %d days');
}
```

This is my View:

```
<tr>
    <th>Age</th>
    <td>{{$profile->getAge()}}</td>
</tr>
```

Is this Right? I am getting error as below

> `Call to a member function diff() on null`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To show directly in your view:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->birth)->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::now())->format('%y years, %m months and %d days');
```

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for +1

Comment: I'm getting like , 0 years, 0 months and 1 days

Answer (score 67):

Dates can be instances of Carbon, which provides an assortment of helpful methods.

In your model, import the Carbon class:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

And define an accessor:

```
/**
 * Accessor for Age.
 */
public function age()
{
    return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['birthdate'])->age;
}
```

You can then call `age` as if it was a regular attribute. For example in a blade view:

```
<p>{{ $user->age() }} years</p>
```

Comment: Since title says "... Laravel 5.2" it might be helpful to mention that this method still works with Laravel 5.6 and, not tested in 5.7 yet but guessing it would do the same.

Comment: @alext I can confirm this still works for Laravel 7.x

Comment: Acessors are better defined as `public function getAgeAttribute()` and then to call you would only need `{{ $user->age }}`

Answer (score 6):

I added this code in my Model:

```
protected $appends = ['age'];

public function getAgeAttribute()
{
   return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['birthday'])->age;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In laravel 7:

```
$dateOfBirth = '1990-01-01';
$years = \Carbon::parse($dateOfBirth)->age;
  
dd($years); // 31
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all you suggestion.

That was easy and awesome with carbon.

I added this code in Model:

```
public function age() {
return $this->dob->diffInYears(\Carbon::now());
 }
```

Comment: @frvanhove I also manage to get change the date format 'Y-m-d' from database  to passing date in this 'd-m-Y' in view . I place this code in model  `public function getDOB(){
            return $this->dob->format('d-m-Y');
        }`

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the age in Laravel is best done using the build in Carbon.
Dates returned in Laravel are already in a Carbon format.

This logic should go in the model as a default getter for your model.

```
public function getAge(){
    $this->birthdate->diff(Carbon::now())
         ->format('%y years, %m months and %d days');
}
```

This will result in "23 years, 6 months and 26 days"

Checkout the http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ docs for all the fun stuff you can do with it.

Assuming you are using models in your view and since you should make a `getAge()` function in that model.

You can call your model in the view as `$user->getAge()`

Comment: I tried as you mentioned , I am getting an error , I have edited my question , Please can you go through again. Let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: Seems like you figured it out ;)

Comment: Thanks for you help!

Comment: Does this work independent of the position of the day and month format? Like if a person's birthday is 3rd February, how does it know it isn't 2nd March?

Comment: you should parse $this->birthdate before otherwise you might get an error e.g. " Call to a member function diff() on string"

Comment: 0 years, 0 months and 1 days

Answer (score 1):

```
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;

Route::get('/userage',function(){

    $user_info = User::find(1);
    // When  ( $table->date('birthday'); ) 
    $birthday = $user_info->birthday;
    $user_age = Carbon::parse($birthday)->diff(Carbon::now())->format('%y years, %m months and %d days');

    echo($user_age); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also manage to get change the date format 'Y-m-d' from database to passing date in this 'd-m-Y' in view .

I place this code in model

```
public function getDOB(){ 
return $this->dob->format('d-m-Y'); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your blade template do this

```
@php
    $birthday = $user->date_of_birth;
    $age = Carbon\Carbon::parse($birthday)->diff(Carbon\Carbon::now())->format('%y years, %m months and %d days');
@endphp

        <p>{{$age}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In User.php Model in Laravel:
Added this functions

```
public function getAge() {
    $format = '%y years, %m months and %d days';
    return \Carbon\Carbon::parse(auth()->user()->dateofbirth)->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::now())->format($format);
}
```

In View Blade:

```
Age: {{ auth()->user()->getAge() }}
```