# Calculate Age for each user from array of date using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i'm new to laravel i want to know if there are methode to calculate age from array so my content looks like this:

```
  Collection {#231 ▼
      #items: array:6 [▼
        0 => "1928-11-18"
        1 => "1938-06-15"
        2 => "1939-03-30"
        3 => "1941-11-08"
        4 => "1940-04-29"
        5 => "1987-06-24"
      ]
    }
```

How to properly transform the array so that it contains only age like this

```
Collection {#231 ▼
      #items: array:6 [▼
        0 => 90
        1 => 80
        2 => 79
        3 => 77
        4 => 87
        5 => 31
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524482/calculate-age-from-date-stored-in-database-in-y-m-d-using-laravel-5-2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use map method on collection

```
$collection = collect([0 => "1928-11-18",
            1 => "1938-06-15",
            2 => "1939-03-30",
            3 => "1941-11-08",
            4 => "1940-04-29",
            5 => "1987-06-24"]);

            $age = $collection->map(function ($item, $key) {
                return Carbon::parse($item)->diff(Carbon::now())->format('%y');
            });

           return $age->all();
```

This will give you,

```
[
"89",
"79",
"79",
"76",
"78",
"30"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Carbon's `->age` or `diffInYears`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) and collection [transform](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-transform) (or map):

```
$dates->transform(function ($date) {
    return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)->age;
});
```

Note: someone born on `1928-11-18` is 89 years old, not 90.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate trough a Collection with [`foreach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-collections#introduction) then convert to Age using Carbon [`->age`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters):

```
foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
    $collection[$key] = Carbon::parse($collection[$key])->age;
}
```

This will give you a Collection as what you do is editing the Collection, instead of creating a new array.