# Calculate age in a list with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a list of users, where each user has "N" pets and one of the attributes is the Pet's birth date. How can I take that date of birth of the animal that is in a List and calculate the age and present it in the List?

```
public function index()
    {
        $pets =  Auth::user()->pets()->get();      
        return view('auth.pets.list',compact('pets'));        
    }
```

Comment: Pls share your code to help

Comment: I just added more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

age calculation by using Laravel carbon.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$dateOfBirth = '1994-07-02';
$years = Carbon::parse($dateOfBirth)->age;
```

As per your code.

```
@if(!empty($pets))
    @foreach($pets as $pet)
        {{ Carbon::parse($pet->date_birth)->age ?? 0 }} years
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: But how do I get the birth date from my list of Pets?

Comment: Remove `@if(!empty($pets))` check. It's not needed.

Comment: `!empty` is for checking the `$pets` have value or not? if you remove `!empty ` condition and `$pets` is an empty array then you'll get the empty object foreach error.

Comment: Understand. I'll try. Can I put this directly in my View, in pets.blade.php or just in PetsController.php?

Comment: this will be in your blade file. `auth.pets.list` in `list.blade.php` file you can access it. :)

Answer (score 1):

To directly show age in your view you can use this:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($pet->date_birth)->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::now())->format('%y years, %m months and %d days');
```

Reference:
[Calculate Age from date stored in database in Y-m-d using Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524482/calculate-age-from-date-stored-in-database-in-y-m-d-using-laravel-5-2)